# Python no crea archivo json

Tags: python

nesesito guardar un diccionario en un archivo json. Sin embargo, corro el siguiente codigo y luego reviso la carpeta y no lo encuentro... algo esta mal. Ayuda porfavor,

```
with open("dump.json", "w") as f:
json.dump(dic1, f)
```

Comment: El código, identando la segunda linea es correcto (supongo que es un error al copiar, porque tendrias un IdentationError), eso te crea el fichero en el **directorio de trabajo del script en ese momento, que no tiene que ser necesariamente el que contiene el módulo**, puedes asegurarte de que estás buscando en el directorio correcto con `import os; print("DIRECTORIO:",  os.getcwd())`. Ante las dudas, puedes listar los archivos JSON del directorio, después de que el bloque `with` termine,  con `import glob; print(glob.glob('./*.json'))`

Comment: el codigo que pusiste esta mal indentado :/